# Adding Multiple Dict Value against a Single Key

Tags: python

I am doing following:

```
>>> l = []
>>> l
[]
>>> l
[]
>>> d = {}
>>> d['Title'] = {'Age':4}
>>> d
{'Title': {'Age': 4}}
>>> l.append(d)
>>> l
[{'Title': {'Age': 4}}]
>>> d['Title'] = {}
>>> d['Title'] = {'Age':21}
>>> l.append(d)
>>> l
[{'Title': {'Age': 21}}, {'Title': {'Age': 21}}]
```

Instead of showing Age 4 and 21 it repeats the last value. Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d` is just a reference. So when you change `d` and append it `l` again, you have effectively added the same object twice to `l`. You can either:

- Use a different dictionary variable the second time.
- Use `del` before you re-use `d`. Like this:

  ```
  In [58]: d = {}
  In [59]: l = []
  In [60]: d['Title'] = {'Age':4}
  In [61]: l.append(d)
  In [62]: del d
  In [63]: d = {}
  In [64]: d['Title'] = {'Age':21}
  In [65]: l.append(d)
  In [66]: l
  Out[66]: [{'Title': {'Age': 4}}, {'Title': {'Age': 21}}]
  ```
- Use copy

  ```
  In [72]: d = {}
  In [73]: l = []
  In [74]: d['Title'] = {'Age':4}
  In [75]: l.append(d.copy())
  In [76]: d['Title'] = {'Age':21}
  In [77]: l.append(d)
  In [78]: l
  Out[78]: [{'Title': {'Age': 4}}, {'Title': {'Age': 21}}]
  ```

Answer (score 2):

You reused the same dictionary object you already added to `l`. If you meant to add a *new* dictionary, create a new object:

```
l = []
d = {'Title': {'Age': 4}}
l.append(d)
d = {'Title': {'Age': 21}}
l.append(d)
```

where I used a dictionary literal to create the whole structure in one go.

Alternatively, create a copy of `d` to add to `l`:

```
l.append(d.copy())
```

which creates a shallow copy of `d`.

Python lists hold *references*, not copies.

Answer (score 1):

if you check [`id`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) of these objects they are all the same:

```
>>> l
[{'Title': {'Age': 4}}]
>>> id(l[0])
139978373813960
>>> id(d)
139978373813960
>>> d['Title'] = {}
>>> id(d)
139978373813960
>>> d['Title'] = {'Age':21}
>>> id(d)
139978373813960
>>> l.append(d)
>>> id(l[0])
139978373813960
>>> id(l[1])
139978373813960
```

Answer (score 0):

With all these good answers, my one cent: `id()` is useful in this case to show that you have two incidence of the same dictionary in your list, rather than two different dictionaries:

```
In [13]: id.__doc__
Out[13]: "id(object) -> integer\n\nReturn the identity of an object.  This is guaranteed to be unique among\nsimultaneously existing objects.  (Hint: it's the object's memory address.)"

In [14]: l = []

In [15]: d={}

In [16]: d['Title'] = {'Age':4}

In [17]: l.append(d)

In [18]: d['Title'] = {}

In [19]: d['Title'] = {'Age':21}

In [20]: l.append(d)

In [21]: map(id, l)
Out[21]: [4386697552, 4386697552] #identical
```